# Does having multiple URIs mapping to the same resource help SEO?

Tags: seo

Let's say I have a site with products that have tags, if each resource is available at

```
GET '/products/tagged/:tag_list/:product_permalink'
```

Could that be better for SEO than just one permalink?

For example a product tagged "tea" and "coffee" would be available at

```
GET '/products/tagged/tea/:product_permalink'
GET '/products/tagged/coffee/:product_permalink'
GET '/products/tagged/tea/coffee/:product_permalink'
GET '/products/tagged/coffee/tea/:product_permalink'
```

I would imagine that google would appreciate this because it gives multiple URIs with different levels of detail about the product, but I cant really be certain. Anyone have any direct knowledge on the topic?

**--EDIT--**
As John Conde points, this is a horrible idea. What about having the links on my site link to a route such as `GET '/products/tagged/:full_tag_list/:product_permalink'`, and then any time a user changes tags just have a HTTP moved permanently status to the new URL. Therefore duplicate URLs would be highly unlikely and mitigated by the proper response. Would this be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the exact opposite of what search engines want. Pulling up the same content with multiple URLs causes duplicate content issues. Search engines want one URL per page. Having more than one, with Google at least, can cause those pages to rank poorly and, if you have too much duplicate content, cause your site to be considered low quality and removed from the search results (or ranked so poorly you essentially are not in the search results any more).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm glad I didn't waste my time creating an elaborate route matching system. Is there anywhere I can find like a "SEO guide for webmasters and developers"? I see a lot of guides aimed towards the common wordpress/social media user, but nothing that really stands out?

Comment: @Brian I have started working on this, but it is still new and work in progress: http://ligatures.net/content/expertise/seo-guidelines-and-checklists.html